# What is the easiest way to build a private website network based on Linkedin profiles?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, social-media, networking

What is the easiest way to build a private website network based on Linkedin profiles? Are there any pre-built softwares/webapps that can do this? Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

This is what inspired my question. Taken from The Next Web Conference: http://thenextweb.com/eu/2011/04/25/taking-conference-networking-to-the-next-level/

> We’ve built a private (mobile) business network, that works on any phone, tablet and laptop but is only accessible to attendees of TNW2011. It really takes networking to the next level. We tested a first version of this network at a previous conference and it delivered so much more value for people, that some of them told us they would happily pay 500 euros extra for an event as long as they offered this tool too.

This is what I'm aiming to replicate.

> The network allows you to:
>
> - Browse and search through all attendees
> - Set up meetings on and around the event with attendees
> - Meet potential clients
> - Ask for introductions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you're thinking of building in, but here's a PHP library based on the LinkedIn API.

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1439

Answer (score 1):

Linkedin has an API and [this site](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/linkedin/mashups) has some example applications that use it. I think that would be a good place to start.